# YAML error with docker compose file for hyperledger fabric

Tags: docker, yaml, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to get hyperledger fabric running using the following docker-compose.yml file.  The file and error are copied below.  Any idea what might be causing this and how best to resolve the issue?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
membersrvc:
   image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
   ports:
     - "7054:7054"
   command: membersrvc
 vp0:
   image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
   ports:
     - "7050:7050"
     - "7051:7051"
     - "7053:7053"
   environment:
     - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
     - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
     - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
     - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
     - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
     - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
     - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
     - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true
     - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0
     - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT
   links:
     - membersrvc
   command: sh -c "sleep 5; peer node start --peer-chaincodedev"
```

**error when running docker-compose up**

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the space before `vp0` on line 6. This is at the wrong level of indentation to be a top-level block, and at the wrong level to be a block within `membersrvc`.